# C# Pass data to array

Tags: c#

I finally got all my parsing working with one exception.

the following code works exactly as it should

```
public void GetCurrentSchedule()
    {


        String JSONstring = File.ReadAllText("\\USER\\Schedule\\Schedule.txt");
        RootObject p1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JSONstring);


        for (int a = i; a <= (i + 3); a++)
        {
            sDay = p1.schedulePeriods[a].day;
            sPeriod = p1.schedulePeriods[a].periodType;
            sStart = p1.schedulePeriods[a].startTime;
            sCancel= p1.schedulePeriods[a].isCancelled;
            sHeat = p1.schedulePeriods[a].heatSetpoint;
            sCool = p1.schedulePeriods[a].coolSetpoint;
            sFan = p1.schedulePeriods[a].fanMode;

            Console.PrintLine("day: {0}", sDay);
            Console.PrintLine("period: {0}", sPeriod);
            Console.PrintLine("start: {0}", sStart);
            Console.PrintLine("Cancel: {0}", sCancel);
            Console.PrintLine("Heat: {0}", sHeat);
            Console.PrintLine("Cool: {0}", sCool);
            Console.PrintLine("Fan: {0}", sFan);
        }

    }
```

however what i want to do is assign each pass to array to be called later by index number.

for example

```
sDay = p1.schedulePeriods[a].day;
```

i want to have 4 indexes of sDay that i can call by index number from another class.

I have been beating my head against the wall trying to get this working.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is 2017. You probably shouldn't be using arrays anymore

Comment: So how would you do this?

Comment: It's simple declare and array and populate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like this?

```
public void GetCurrentSchedule()
{


    String JSONstring = File.ReadAllText("\\USER\\Schedule\\Schedule.txt");
    RootObject p1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JSONstring);
    string[] sDay = new string[i + 4];//Declare your array here (+4 becuase your for loop goes upto +3)

    for (int a = i; a <= (i + 3); a++)
    {
        sDay[a - i] = p1.schedulePeriods[a].day; // assign the value to  array element (a - i because if i > 0 because arrays start with 0)
        sPeriod = p1.schedulePeriods[a].periodType;
        sStart = p1.schedulePeriods[a].startTime;
        sCancel= p1.schedulePeriods[a].isCancelled;
        sHeat = p1.schedulePeriods[a].heatSetpoint;
        sCool = p1.schedulePeriods[a].coolSetpoint;
        sFan = p1.schedulePeriods[a].fanMode;

        Console.PrintLine("day: {0}", sDay[a - i]); // Call it with index
        Console.PrintLine("period: {0}", sPeriod);
        Console.PrintLine("start: {0}", sStart);
        Console.PrintLine("Cancel: {0}", sCancel);
        Console.PrintLine("Heat: {0}", sHeat);
        Console.PrintLine("Cool: {0}", sCool);
        Console.PrintLine("Fan: {0}", sFan);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<string> SDays = new List<string>(); // or whatever type     


        //  inside method
        String JSONstring = File.ReadAllText("\\USER\\Schedule\\Schedule.txt");
        RootObject p1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JSONstring);

        for (int a = i; a <= (i + 3); a++)
        {
            SDays.Add(p1.schedulePeriods[a].day);
            //and so on
        }
```

Call `SDays[index]` to get correct day from another class

You'll probably want to change it to a cleaner OOP style, too.